# Android studio "Clear All" in log cat, logs still come back when changing log level filter

Tags: android, logging, android-studio, logcat

In LogCat, when I click the "clear all" button, it appears to clear all of the logs. However, if I change the log level, and come back to the previous log level, all of the logs have returned.

For example, I'm looking at "Verbose". I choose "Clear all". The log clears. I switch over to "Debug". I switch back to "Verbose", now all of the Verbose logs that I thought I cleared, have now come back. It displays everything since I opened Android Studio.

Additionally, the same issue occurs if I clear all, and then re-launch my app; I get flooded with old debug messages before seeing any new ones.

**Is there any way to remove the logs for good, without having to restart Android Studio?**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following screenshot is from Android Studio 1.1 Beta 4.

[image: Android Studio - clear logs from UI]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just noticed that the title of that button is indeed **Clear logcat**

Comment: On Android Studio this button actually clears connected device log as well. for clearing the log console only , right click>> clear all. sadly, even in 1.3, both of these two icon are same.

Comment: @IronBlossom, please take a closer look at the question: the OP already knows about right click→clear all option.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from Android-studio GUI
but from command line you can call

> adb logcat -c