# How do you clear the Android Studio Logcat console log?

Tags: debugging, android-studio, logcat

I would like to clear the contents of the Android Studio Logcat console log.

How do you clear the current contents of the log?

Comment: Related post - [Android studio “Clear All” in log cat, logs still come back when changing log level filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28144166/465053)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Clear Logcat` "trash" button is located to the left of the Logcat console.

I find that in Android Studio version 1.0.1 you must then additionally click the `Reset` button. Otherwise, the console stops logging after `Clear Logcat` is pressed. I am not sure if this is intended behavior.

[image: Clear and then Reset Logcat]

Answer (score 12):

If you cannot see the toolbar, right-click on the logcat screen and click `Show Toolbar`
After that you may click trash-bin icon on top of it.

Comment: For me, the option appeared when clicking the Logcat tab.